# Breadcrumbs in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs

I have a breadcrumb in my current WordPress theme and I want the breadcrumb Home not to be displayed on Home page because I get Home > Home.

How can I set the following rule: If on home page do not display the first "Home" word?

Thanks guys!

Here is the code from theme:

```
// Breadcrumb

function the_breadcrumb() {
    global $post;
    echo '<nav class="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><ol>';
    if (!is_home()) {
        echo '<li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="';
        echo get_option('home');
        echo '" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">';
        echo '<span itemprop="title"><strong>Home</strong></span>';
        echo '</span></a></li>';
        if (is_category() || is_single()) {
            echo '<li itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">';
            the_category(' </li><li itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"> ');
            if (is_single()) {
                echo '</li><li itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">';
                the_title();
                echo '</li>';
            }
        } elseif (is_page()) {
            if($post->post_parent){
                $anc = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
                $title = get_the_title();
                foreach ( $anc as $ancestor ) {
                    $output = '<li itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="'.get_permalink($ancestor).'" title="'.get_the_title($ancestor).'" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">'.get_the_title($ancestor).'</span></a></li>';
                }
                echo $output;
                echo '<li class="pag_actual" itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><span itemprop="title"> '.$title.'</span></li>';
            } else {
                echo '<li class="pag_actual" itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><span itemprop="title"><strong> '.get_the_title().'</strong></span></li>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe try to remove code that represents the `home` link? Lines 6 - 11 should do the job.